# Can I store nullptr to bool?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, shortcut, nullptr

I have a function that returns a pointer to an object of type bool for a given name. If the object is not found, `nullptr` is returned.

Now I would like to set a variable to the value of the returned boolean or false if not found. Can I write it like this?

```
bool flag = *Get("name");
```

Is this equivalent to this longer implementation?

```
bool *result = Get("name");
bool flag = result == nullptr ? false : *result;
```

Comment: You'd be better off overloading with a `bool Get(const char* identifier, bool if_missing)` function (or `get_with_default(...)` if you prefer), so you can say `bool flag = Get("name", false);`.  Many interfaces use this approach.

Comment: @TonyD This sounds very interesting. Unfortunately, the get function actually is templatized like `Get<T>(std::string Key)` and thus, proving a fallback is not that easy for all types. For types without default constructor, I couldn't default it like `T *Fallback = new T()`.

Comment: @danijar: that can still work. Consider the `vector::resize` function in C++03 (it changed in C++11). It has a default argument that uses the default constructor. If the type doesn't have a default constructor then the function still compiles but the caller *must* provide the argument.

Comment: @danijar: `template <typename T> T Get(const char* identifier, const T& if_missing) { T* p = Get(identifier); return p ? *p : if_missing; }`... no?  You don't need a default constructor - you can let the caller specify the fallback value they want as the second `if_missing` argument (though sometimes it's nice to offer a default-constructed default value for that argument).  (This was going through my mind when I suggested overloading "Get" where the `if_missing` was mandatory to ensure the new behaviour, versus a `get_with_default` where you could provide a defaulted 2nd argument).

Comment: @TonyD This would make the interface more complex, that's why I won't use this approach here. But thanks for telling me the interesting concept though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is not correct since you cannot dereference a null pointer.

The second is correct but simplifies to:

```
bool flag = result && *result;
```

If you want to avoid the `result` variable for each call then do it like:

```
bool istrue(bool const *result) {
    return result && *result;
}

bool flag = istrue(Get("name"));
```

Answer (score 2):

No it's not equivalent. In the first case, if your method returns nullptr, you'll probably get runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not equivalent. In the first case you are trying to dereference `nullptr` which will crash while in the second you do a proper check first.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want something that can be `nullptr`, `true` or `false`.

The boost libraries (www.boost.org) have an `optional` class which you could exploit:

```
boost::optional<bool> foo;
```

This allows you to check for nullness using `if (!foo)`, and if the converse is true then you use `*` to recover the boolean value.

Comment: In many ways yes (reduces the overhead of a heavyweight 3rd party library). But boost::optional does allow you to treat `foo` as a variable in itself.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not equivalent. The first implementation will cause a segmentation fault (as you will be attempting to dereference a NULL pointer).

The second alternative is correct.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I haven't seen this. Is there another way to accomplish the desired behavior without using a helper `result` variable?

Comment: @danijar: If you can't modify the interface of `Get` but you want to avoid a `result` variable then either call `Get` twice or else write a function and pass the result of `Get` into it.

Comment: @SteveJessop I decided to go with the second option.